Increase boot (xfs) partition
I need to increase the /dev/sda2 partition where the RHEL8 system mounts the boot partition, using the remaining space at the right, e.g. adding 1GiB to sda2


I tried booting with GPARTED (where the screens came) but I'm not able to move the lvm2 partition to the right.
Is there a way to increase the /dev/sda2 partition without destroy the lvm2 one?
Thank you, Lucas

This should be possible to do fairly quickly, but no one implemented such a software (at least I don't know one). For now, you have to use other storage disk, temporarily move volumes to it; no need to copy files, only volumes, you can even do it online without booting gparted. But please, satisfy my curiosity, why you want to do that? 1GiB is a plenty for /boot (I'd argue it's too much), you have half of it free, and you probably can free some more by removing old unused kernels (left there after updates).

Thanks Nikita, currently I solved creating a new sda4 partion and move the /boot mount to that new partition. I need space in /boot because I have to create REAR environment to boot from, and some other isos like clonezilla, gparted, etc... to boot from too. As in work environment I don't have the ability to attach ISO and boot from it.
